# Nginx + PHP-FPM 4GB Ram optimization

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php-fpm

So I have it all running, no errors, but I'm trying to optimise it for a 4gb Rackspace Cloud server.

This is what I have currently:

**php-fpm.conf**

```
pm.max_children = 200
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_spare_servers = 60
pm.max_requests = 100
```

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes 4;
events {
        worker_connections 2000;
        # multi_accept on;
}
```

**php.ini**

```
memory_limit = 16m;
```

Just doesn't seem to perform as well as my Apache2 setup with the same server when runnning

```
ab -n 30000 -c 350 http://domain.com/
```

Comment: Posted on the wrong site. Belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: ab is for testing apache2. Try http_load: http://acme.com/software/http_load/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to tweak and adjust until you find your sweet spot but "pm.max_requests = 100" seems very low. Something like 500 or 1000 or maybe more, might be better. Fastcgi will have to kill and respawn children after each one serves pm.max_requests.

PHP memory should not directly impact speed and is the same for both test targets or yours but "memory_limit = 16m;" is low. Start at 256M. You have 4GB of RAM so why limit PHP to a measly 16mb max?

Comment: I'd also add, I think you do not need 60 spare servers, fewer would be enough, but do raise max_requests.

Comment: I thought that php's memory_limit was the limit on memory that a php process could use, if the php script he runs doesnt require more memory why increase it? in fpm-php this means the worker process would consume more memory and limit the number of spawned process or did I get it wrong?