# Nginx very slow. Changed from Apache2 to Nginx

Tags: nginx, debian, configuration

I recently changed my server from Apache to Nginx. That's because the website was using file_get_contents to another website. When that external website was down or slow, the threads were maxed out and the server went down. It's like a domino effect.

I then upgraded the server from Apache2 to Nginx together with a reverse proxy also running Nginx. This way, I can run multiple servers with multiple domains on 1 single IP Address.

Today I noticed the visitors were dropping hard, and acted quick. The server is very slow and even gets a few Timeouts.

---

**I have 3 servers:**

1. Reverse Proxy - Nginx (Main connection to internet)
2. 1st Website - Nginx (about 10,000 unique visitors a day)
3. 2nd website - Apache2 (Experimental website, very quick response)

When connecting to the 1st website, it is VERY slow (about 28 seconds wait time), but when connecting to the 2nd website, it's very quick (about 0.8 seconds wait time)

I have very little knowledge of Nginx at the time, as I have been using Apache2 for 2 years now.

---

**Reverse Proxy - /etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

*Yes, I have a bunch of domains on that first one*

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com domain.org www.domain.org domain.co.uk www.domain.co.uk domain.co www.domain.co domain.me www.domain.me domain.se www.domain.se;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.237;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
        real_ip_recursive on;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        }
}
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.domain2.com domain2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.230;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name controller.domain.com;

    location / {
        allow 84.71.x.x/21;
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        }
}
```

**1st webserver - /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 10;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**1st webserver - /etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/pi;
        index index.php;

        # It seems like the server only needed 1 of these, as all the other domains redirects to the main domain
        server_name domain.com domain.org;

        error_page 404 /missing.php;
        error_page 403 /forbidden.php;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

---

I'm not sure where the problem lies, so I linked a few config files.

I used some of [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-an-apache-web-server-to-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps) (I did not change the ports, but simply stopped apache, installed nginx and then uninstalled apache) to move from Apache to Nginx.

All computers are running Debian.

There are currently around 4600 requests per hour which I counted with this command: `sudo grep -o '13/Feb/2018:09:' /var/log/nginx/access.log | wc -l`

Do you have any recommendations or things I could try to solve this?

---

### EDIT

The problem seems to occur when under high load.

---

### UPDATE

The server seems to be working fine now.
I found [this link](https://www.howtoforge.com/installing-php-5.3-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-debian) and used the config as an example. Then I removed/edited to match the infrastructure (Reverse proxy, custom parameters).

[Here is a visual representation (Monitorix) of the server status for the last week/day.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UHLn.jpg) I added a description on the images.

I'll let the server keep running as the configuration is at the moment, and see if I come across any future errors.

### UPDATE 2

It has almost been a week, and I was hoping the problem were sovlved...
The problem has come back.

Now it constantly throws this error:

```
2018/02/17 18:52:21 [error] 18185#18185: *2065 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.x.x, server: domain.org, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.org"
```

I also found out that the server got very fast by restarting php5-fpm, but only for about 10 seconds.

I think it is weird that the server has been running fine for a week, and now suddenly this problem occurred again?

RAM is chilling at 1 GB / 4 GB, and the only noticeable different when looking at monitorix (except all network activity dropping) is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeW1K.png). The bump at the end, is when the website is down, but I don't think it matters.

Any recommendations?

### UPDATE 3

I have been holding a close eye on the server for the past week and it has been incredible unstable.
Sometimes i has been very fast, other times it could around 20 seconds to load in the webpage.

I changed the configuration of nginx.conf but only seemed to help a little bit. I started to think the PHP was the problem, not the nginx. I found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/867737/php-loads-slow-on-nginx-server) which linked to an article. I changed a few pm's in www.conf to this:

```
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 8
pm.min_spare_servers = 8
pm.max_spare_servers = 15
pm.max_requests = 500
```

In the last hour, the response time has been around 400 ms.

I'll wait a while and see if the problem occurs again.

Comment: Why are you calling `file_get_contents()` on a remote URL? This is guaranteed to cause you pain, and no web server can fix that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That is to get the html response in a string. From there I can search up certain words or codes, and change it to something else.
Do you have any other recommendations? Is it possible to do this with only Nginx?

Comment: The HTML response of what?

Comment: Maybe not HTML, but I mean the file_get_contents() response from an external website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after nearly a half year later, the problem had occurred again.. Probably because the visitors had nearly doubled, and so it needs more resources.

I downloaded a new monitoring tool called [Netdata](https://github.com/firehol/netdata), and had a close look right after restart of php5-fpm and [found this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElYXn.png).

When the PHP sockets was maxing out, the website got slow. So I found the problem.

After increasing the [resources of PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezMEr.png), it was running fine again

These are my current settings for `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_requests = 2000
```

Yes, this is not the solution for the PHP overload, but rather giving it more resources.

Comment: I have the same problem on an Nginx proxy with no php-fpm. Intermittently high initial load. Guess I'll have to keep digging since this doesn't help. Great information, though!

Comment: @DevOpsSauce My case was a bit niche, for nginx being slow I would guess something somewhere is maxed out. I don't think installing a monitoring tool for the servers in question is a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

First I would try to find out what part of the chain makes the website slow.

1. Check your slow website with [www.webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org).

   - If 'Time to First Byte' value is high -> Could be a networking, dns, caching or nginx related issue.
   - If initial request takes very long to complete -> Could be PHP, Database, Application or caching related issue.
2. Activate timing variabels for nginx logging so you might get more info out of your log files. See [Using NGINX Logging for Application Performance Monitoring](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-logging-for-application-performance-monitoring/). Check nginx logs on both reverse proxy and application server.
3. If problems get worse under higher load you can simluate load unsing the `ab` tool. For example to send 3000 requests with 100 concurrent requests use:

   ```
   ab -c 100 -n 3000 http://domain.de/
   ```

   I also use this to check if my PHP-fpm pool socket file settings work well under load.
4. Is the slowness file size dependent? Look for packet sizes, buffering and keepalive values.
5. Other issues? Failing hard drive, switching issue, other processes on server eat up CPU/RAM?

Comment: So the configuration seems to be right?

Comment: Yes, at least nothing obvious for me to see that could cause a 28 seconds delay. Most likely it is a configuration issue. I would try to find the slow part first and then look into the details like described above.

Comment: Hi. The problems seems to occur when many users are waiting for a PHP code at the same time. However, looking at the stats, the RAM is the only thing maxed out (4 GB RAM). So I restarted the server and it was very fast and responsive... for only about 1 minute, then it got slow/504 timeout. The server goes down whenever I route all traffic to it. (switching between a backup server and the 1st webserver). The problem has something to do with overload.

Comment: Maybe you spawn too many PHP-fpm children (see your PHP-fpm pool config file for details) so you run out of memory. Low free RAM can cause issues for caches, temp fs, buffering and database connection. With only 4GB RAM you need to know what you are doing to handle high traffic and can't afford to waste memory. Look for special instructions from other how to optimizie RAM usage in such situations – like [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/315238/nginx-php-fpm-4gb-ram-optimization) or [here](https://reviewsignal.com/blog/2014/06/25/40-million-hits-a-day-on-wordpress-using-a-10-vps/).